# Symfony security: Access control rules break after Symfony 6.1 update

Tags: symfony

I recently upgraded a Symfony 5.4 project to 6.1. After the upgrade I can't open the start page anymore. The `/login` page and logging in with a user still works.

The error shown on any other page is pretty cryptic:

> ErrorException: **Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched
> closing parenthesis at offset 2**
>
> at vendor/symfony/http-foundation/**RequestMatcher.php:165**
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestMatcher->matches(object(Request))
> (vendor/symfony/security-http/**AccessMap.php:42**)

If I comment out all `access_control` in `security.yaml` I can navigate around the page again, so I assume the error is somewhere in those rules. I have looked at https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html but can't figure out why my config is broken. Is this the source of the error message?

This is my `security.yaml`:

```yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: security_login
            form_login:
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                enable_csrf: true
                default_target_path: default_index
            entry_point: form_login
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/login$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/registration, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/resetting, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/locale, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/_error, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/), roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message basically tells you what's wrong.

Your last access_control rule uses a closing parenthesis ")". In Regex this is a reserved character. If this is not a mistake and you actually have routes starting with a closing parenthesis, then you will have to escape the character like so:

```yaml
- { path: ^/\), roles: ROLE_USER }
```